# Why is wp api returning old acf values?

Tags: custom-post-types, javascript, advanced-custom-fields, wp-api

I have a list of custom post types (Events) with ACF fields for start and end dates that I'm getting using WP-API. I'm using the fetch api to make the calls. I have the acf-to-rest-api plugin installed and activated. I'm using the lastest versions of everything.

I changed the start and end date fields of an event after it had been created. The new values are displayed in the post editor, and when I dig into the actual database it's got the correct updated values. But the WP-API call is return the old value. What could be going on?

I've tried clearing all caches I could think of, messed around with transients... anything else?

Comment: Versions: WP v4.9.7, ACF (Pro) v5.6.10, ACF to REST API v3.1.0, Custom Post Type UI v1.5.8, PHP v7.2.1, MySQL v5.6.38, Chrome  v67.0.3396.99

Comment: Sure it's not just the browser cache? What do you see if you open the request URL in an incognito window, or a different browser?

Comment: @JacobPeattie yep, different browsers, postman, all returning the same old value. The problem was actually caught by the client after they changed the event date, and instead of changing dates it just disappeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem and I'm embarrassed... I had hardcoded one of the request urls in my js, but used the url to the staging site. So the value wasn't updated because the value in the staging site hadn't changed. #facepalm#